Windows WSL has no internet connection
My WSL has no internet connection. I have tried solutions at here and the problem still exists. Does anyone have suggestions? Thanks in advance.


I was also having the same issue and tried all the possibilities mentioned in the post you referenced. What ultimately worked was following these steps to force WSL to use the network as a mirror on the Host:

On your Windows machine, create the .wslconfig file inside your user's folder (e.g., C:\Users\<user>\).
Fill this file with the following configuration:

[wsl2]
networkingMode=mirrored


Open a terminal as an administrator and shut down WSL: wsl --shutdown.
Enter your WSL distribution and perform a ping test.


Thanks for your suggestion. After I added .wslconfig inside C:\Users<user>\ as you suggested, it still does not have internet access.
